# Finding number of overlapping ranges for a given input range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, segment

What I have as input is a `Range[] arr` of size `n` where `Range` is

```
class Range{
    int upper, lower;
    Range(int upper,int lower){
        this.upper=upper;
        this.lower=lower;
    }

}
```

Now, for `q` queries, I get a `Range r` as input and I have to report the number of values in `arr` from index `L` to `R`(which is also given as input for each query),where a `Range` in `arr` is considered valid only if it's upper value is greater than `r.upper` and lower is less than `r.lower`.

I was thinking of using a merge sort tree, but I cannot figure out how to integrate both the conditions. Please suggest some data structure for which construction complexity as well as query complexity is  `O(n.log n)` and `O(q.log n)` respectively.

Also, it should be noted that only the ranges within a particular segment is considered, which is also given as input.

PS: Some modification on merge sort tree or segment tree seems probable, so any answer with merge sort tree or segment tree is welcome.

**EDIT** : 
R[] = { {3,7} , {5,9} , {2,10} , {4,10} , {3,5}  }

query #1 : {4,6},  l = 2 , r = 5

here, the ranges considered are {5,9} , {2,10} , {4,10} ,{3,5}

Out of these, only {5,9} , {2,10} , {4,10} are valid.
So answer for this query is 3.

Comment: can you give an example testcase?

Comment: Is it complete overlapping or partial overlapping also counts, for eg. for R[] =  [{1,2}, {1,10}, {5, 9}] for query Q {6,10} , what is the expected answer ?

Comment: It may be possible to solve the task in O(sqrt(n) * n) if you can process queries offline with Mo's algorithm.

Comment: @amit kumar No, partial overlapping does not count